# visual studio (2010) combo box with more layers

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I would like to ask you something about VS2010 combobox (CB) component...
Is it possible to make something like multilevel (categorised) CB? I mean, can I divide items in CB into categories or somthing like this?

There is similar component in html (tag *optgroup*) - it's exactly what I need:

[multilevel combobox in html](http://www.boogiejack.com/html/optgroup.html)

Thanx very much for answer

P.S.: Sorry for my english, I hope I've described it clearly

Comment: For which UI Technologie? Windows Forms, WebForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the `DrawMode` of the `ComboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and you can use the `DrawItem` event to draw your header and your items.  But there is nothing you can do to prevent the user from selecting a header item.

```
private List<string> groupItems = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  groupItems.Add("Great Bands");
  groupItems.Add("Great Bandages");

  comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Great Bands");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Led Zeppelin");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Steppenwolf");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Great Bandages");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Band-Aid");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Curad");
}

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.DrawBackground();

  if (e.Index > -1)
  {
    string drawText = comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    if (groupItems.Contains(drawText))
    {
      using (Font font = new Font(comboBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(drawText, font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
      e.Graphics.DrawString(drawText, comboBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(16, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width - 16, e.Bounds.Height));

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
  }
}
```